# I can't get to the bottom of what is causing an iOS layout engine crash

Tags: swift, multithreading, thread-safety, crashlytics

I am noticing a lot of logs with the following crash in Crashlytics:

> NSISSparseVectorAddTermWithPlaceValueCoefficientStartingIndex
> NSInternalInconsistencyException - Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.

This is a calendar app that uses a silent push notification and a BG task to keep local notifications up to date, and since no user reached out about any crashes, I suspect it's either the silent push or BG task causing the issue, but I am out of ideas for what else to try and I am not sure how to debug this. Here's what I know:

1. I haven't been able to replicate this crash. It never occurs no matter what I do in the app (even simulating sending the silent push from Firebase or waiting for the BG Task).
2. I tried running the app with Main Thread Checker enabled also and it didn't catch anything.
3. The code for the silent push notification is below, and I believe I've done everything I could to make sure anything related to the layout will be performed on the main thread. getCalendarsAndItems() and updatePendingInvites() will make EventKit requests and update some variables, no UI work.

   ```
    import UIKit
    import FirebaseMessaging

    extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
        private func registerForTopic() {
            Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "refreshNotifications") { error in
                if let error = error { print("Failed to subscribe to refreshNotifications topic: \(error.localizedDescription)") }
            }
        }

        func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
            // This delegate method will be called every time the fcm token is retrieved, or changed.
            guard fcmToken != nil else { return }
            registerForTopic()
        }

        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
            registerForTopic()
        }
    }

    extension AppDelegate {
        // This code gets called when a silent push notification is received
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
            EK.shared.eventStore.refreshSourcesIfNecessary()
            track("Reiceved Silent Push")

            if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
                completionHandler(.noData)
                return
            }

            if let lastRefreshDate = UserDefaults.lastNotificationsRefreshDate, !lastRefreshDate.isOlderThanTenMinutes {
                if UIDevice.isMac { Task {
                    try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1 * 1_000_000_000)
                    completionHandler(.noData)
                }}
                return
            }

            Task {
                do {
                    try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 2 * 1_000_000_000)
                    try await DataStorage.getCalendarsAndItems()
                    await DataStorage.updatePendingInvites()
                    UserNotifications.setBadgeNumber()
                    await UserNotifications.updateNotifications(from: "Silent push")
                    WidgetManager.reloadWidgets()
                    UserDefaults.lastNotificationsRefreshDate = Date()
                    if UIDevice.isMac { try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1 * 1_000_000_000) }
                    completionHandler(.newData)
                } catch {
                    if UIDevice.isMac { try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1 * 1_000_000_000) }
                    completionHandler(.failed)
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```

setBadgeNumber looks like this, scheduled on the main thread:

```
static func setBadgeNumber() { // This is used to update the badge number from the foreground
        guard !isSettingBadgeNumber else { return }
        isSettingBadgeNumber = true

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            defer { isSettingBadgeNumber = false }
            #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
            UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0 // Setting the badge number won't work on Catalyst for some reason unless we set it to zero first
            #endif
            if UserDefaults.badgeEnabled {
                UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = DataStorage.pendingInvites.count
            } else { UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0 }
        }
    }
```

4. When refreshSourcesIfNecessary() is called, it may post a notification that a VC is listening to.

   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(eventKitChangesDetected), name: .EKEventStoreChanged, object: nil)

Which then calls

```
@objc func eventKitChangesDetected() {
    if DataStorage.lastManualUpdate?.isOlderThanFiveSeconds ?? true {
        print("EventKit changes detected")
        refreshDataAndLayout()
    } else {
        print("EKEventStoreChanged ignored")
    }
}
```

Which looks like this

```
@objc func refreshDataAndLayout() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active || UIDevice.isMac {
            // This method is called when the EKEventStoreChanged is posted.
            // Because refreshSourcesIfNecessary is called on startup, refreshLayout may end up being called shortly after startup
            Task.detached(priority: .background) {
                do {
                    try await DataStorage.getCalendarsAndItems()
                    await DataStorage.updatePendingInvites()
                    if UserDefaults.calendarLayout == .month { await DataStorage.filterMonthlyEvents() }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.refreshLayout() }
                    await UserNotifications.updateNotifications(from: "Home - refreshDataAndLayout")
                }
                catch { print("Error fetching data on the App Delegate: \(error)") }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea or clue at all for what might be leading to this crash? It seems to occur about 10 times per day according to App Store Analytics (which I know is not fully accurate), but the silent push gets sent 24 times a day to each device, so it's not happening every time.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Finally, this is the stack trace

```
    Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
    0  CoreFoundation                 0xed5e0 __exceptionPreprocess
    1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x2bc00 objc_exception_throw
    2  CoreAutoLayout                 0x57ac NSISSparseVectorAddTermWithPlaceValueCoefficientStartingIndex
    3  CoreAutoLayout                 0xbbc0 -[NSISEngine _optimizeWithoutRebuilding]
    4  CoreAutoLayout                 0xb8d4 -[NSISEngine optimize]
    5  CoreAutoLayout                 0xb660 -[NSISEngine performPendingChangeNotifications]
    6  UIKitCore                      0x334a8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
    7  UIKitCore                      0x32bbc -[_UILabelLayer layoutSublayers]
    8  QuartzCore                     0x67888 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
    9  QuartzCore                     0x67410 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
    10 QuartzCore                     0x6d94c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*)
    11 QuartzCore                     0x66c3c CA::Transaction::commit()
    12 QuartzCore                     0x1fcd70 CA::Transaction::release_thread(void*)
    13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x9f48 _pthread_tsd_cleanup
    14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x4880 _pthread_exit
    15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x5d7c _pthread_wqthread_legacy_worker_wrap
    16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19ec _pthread_wqthread
    17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a04 start_wqthread
```

Comment: It could be any number of places but mixing completion handlers, DispatchQueue and the new concurrency is a sure way to cause random thread crashes. Pick one style new or old.

Comment: @loremipsum I didn't think about that, that's a very good point. What would be the equivalent of DispatchQueue.main.async in the async/await API?

Comment: You can try MainActor.run I personally don’t like it. It is better to use the new concurrencies natural flow but that may be hard here. Don’t use it until the very end when you absolutely have to.

Comment: You should turn on “strict concurrency”

Comment: I will try this, thank you.